# executing: use [dbName] ; exec sp_spaceused with ADO C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, adodb

I am trying to determine the size of a full backub using the query:

```
 use [someDtabase]; exec sp_spaceused
```

If I run it in SSMS it works fine, but when I try to repeat it in C ++ code I get the error: "Operation not allowed when object is closed". My code:

```
std::wstring query = L"use [someDatabase]; exec sp_spaceused";
ADODB::_CommandPtr ptrCommand;
ptrCommand.CreateInstance( __uuidof( ADODB::Command ));
ptrCommand->ActiveConnection = m_ptrConnection;
ptrCommand->CommandText = _bstr_t( query.c_str() );
ptrCommand->CommandTimeout = timeout;
ADODB::_RecordsetPtr ptrRecordset = ptrCommand->Execute( NULL, NULL, ADODB::adCmdText );
if (!ptrRecordset || ptrRecordset->EndOfFile == VARIANT_TRUE) //<--an exception is thrown here
```

I guess the problem is in the "use [someDtabase];" and the recordset is always closed for it

Comment: Seems odd you would include a `USE` in your C++ code, normally your connection string would define the database to use.

Comment: instead of `USE db`, you could execute the procedure in the scope of the database: `exec master.sys.sp_spaceused; exec tempdb.sys.sp_spaceused;`

Answer (score 1):

When messages like "Changed database context" are returned via ADO, the `RecordSet` will be closed, empty, and have no fields. The message(s) will be in the connection `Errors` collection.

You can ignore closed/empty result sets and move to the next with the `RecordSet.NextRecordSet` method. Note that `sp_spaceused` returns 2 result sets anyway so you'll need to invoke `NextRecordSet` again to process the second result.

Note `DONE_IN_PROC` TDS messages (rowcounts) are similarly returned as closed/empty recordsets (but no Errors collection message), which is why `SET NOCOUNT ON` is regularly used for ADO classic applications. Robust data access code should consume all result sets and messages, else SQL exceptions may go undetected.